# Using NSURLConnection to retrieve data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got this api (http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now) that just gives the time as a string and I want to use NSURLConnection to retrieve it, except I'm confused as to how NSURLConnection works.

Current code:

```
+(NSString *) fetchTime
{
    NSString *timeString=@"not_set";

    //Code for URL request here
    NSURL *timeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now"]

    return timeString;
}
```

The method is called from the view controller that will then in turn display it on the screen as per MVC, all I need is a good example to get me in the right direction.

Comment: check this tutorial: http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/how-to-make-http-request-from-iphone-and-parse-json-result/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a request to that api you need something like this:

```
NSURL *timeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now"]
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                        timeoutInterval:120];
NSData *urlData;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                returningResponse:&response
                                            error:&error];

NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is send an Asynchronous request to the server to fetch the Time. If you send out a synchronous request it will block your UI and for some reason if server took a minute to send the response back user wont be able to do anything for a minute. Example using the standard API :

Note that if you are using sync request you can expect a return value but in async calls you would need the help of a block to return the value. So

```
-(void) fetchTimeFromServerWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(id)) onComplete {
            NSURLRequest *timeRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now"]];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:timeRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            // Do something usefull with Data.
            // If expected object is a String, alloc init a String with received Data
            NSString *time = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
            onComplete(time); // This will return back the time string.
        }];
}
```

If you are using service API a lot in your app, you can check out [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#get-request) as well.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: It would make sense to check the result code and the MIME type and the character encoding of the response - before taking something as a string and possibly run into issues later.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper That is why I linked an example to AFNetowrking API. You will get a success/failure block and response has to be checked depending on the service API being called.